# I want to make Spring-Bean Class from POJO Class

Tags: spring, javabeans, pojo

1. servlet-context.xml (part)

   ```
   <context:annotation-config />

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.eai.scard">
   <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />

   <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" />

   </context:component-scan>
   ```
2. target Pojo Class (I want to make this to Spring-bean class)

   ```
   package com.eai.scard.mdm;

   import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

   import javax.annotation.Resource;

   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   other import ...~

   @Component

   public class EmsRcv implements EMSListener {

       private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

       @Resource(name="admstService")
       AdmstService admstService;
   }
   ```
3. Service Class

   ```
   package com.eai.scard.service;

   import javax.annotation.Resource;

   import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

   import com.eai.scard.dao.AdmstDao;
   import com.eai.scard.model.Department;
   import com.eai.scard.model.Employee;

   @Service
   public class AdmstService {

       @Resource(name="admstDao")
       AdmstDao admstDao;

       public int insertDept(Department dept) {
           return admstDao.insertDept(dept);
       }

       public int insertEmp(Employee emp) {
           return admstDao.insertEmp(emp);
       }
   }
   ```
4. DAO Class

   ```
   package com.eai.scard.dao;

   import org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

   import com.eai.scard.model.Department;
   import com.eai.scard.model.Employee;

   @Repository
   public class AdmstDao extends SqlSessionDaoSupport {

       public int insertDept(Department dept) {
           return getSqlSession().insert("admst.insertDept", dept);
       }

       public int insertEmp(Employee emp) {
           return getSqlSession().insert("admst.insertEmp", emp);
       }

   }
   ```

I want to make Spring Bean Class to use the `@Autowired` (or `@Resource`) annotation. But in the above code, `'admstService'` is `null`. What should I do and why did this happen?

Comment: what is the context component scan set ?

Comment: Do you create the instances of `EmsRcv` manually with the `new` keyword?